# How to use the button on one component to remove item from collection to another?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a gallery-item component

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Image} from '../Image';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery-item',
  template: '<mat-card class="example-card">\
        <mat-card-header>\
          <mat-card-title>{{image.title}}</mat-card-title>\
        </mat-card-header>\
        <img mat-card-image [src]="image.url">\
        <button mat-button (click)="onDeleteImage($event, image.id)">DELETE</button>\
  </mat-card>',
  styleUrls: ['./gallery-item.component.css']
})
export class GalleryItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  image: Image;
}
```

And I have a component gallery

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Image} from '../image';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery-container',
  template: '<app-gallery-item *ngFor="let image of images" [image]="image">\
    </app-gallery-item>',
  styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.css']
})
export class GalleryContainerComponent  {
  @Input()
  images: Image[];

  onDeleteImage(event, index: number) {
    console.log('Delete image');
    for (let i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
      if (this.images[i].id === index) {
        this.images.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I need to click the DELETE button to delete the image from the gallery. I tried to implement it, but I encountered this problem. The browser writes that onDeleteImage is not a function and ERROR CONTEXT. I understand that I can not correctly link these two components. Please help me solve this problem

Comment: does GalleryItemComponent and GalleryContainerComponent  has common parent?

Comment: onDeleteImage is a member of the parent component. it won't work on any different component

Comment: I think by default everything is public in typescript @Roysh.

Comment: @Roysh onDeleteImage is not defined inside GalleryItemComponent. Hence not a function error

Comment: You need to take a look at this. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction.
You could pass data or action to parent - child or vice versa.

Comment: u need to use service with events or @ViewChild to call another component function

Comment: Ideally your GalleryContainerComponent is parent of GalleryItemComponent. So you could use an `eventemitter` to publish the command and subscribe it in GalleryItemComponent and use it.

Comment: I have edited my answer so it should work now, or at least give you the way of solving the this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onDeleteImage is on the parent component and not on the child where the click event triggers.

If you desire to keep that function in the parent component, what you need to do is to emit an event from the child component to the parent one.

How do you do that?

Add an output to your child component and make it emit and event

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Image} from '../Image';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery-item',
  template: '<mat-card class="example-card">\
        <mat-card-header>\
          <mat-card-title>{{image.title}}</mat-card-title>\
        </mat-card-header>\
        <img mat-card-image [src]="image.url">\
        <button mat-button (click)="deleteImage()">DELETE</button>\
  </mat-card>',
  styleUrls: ['./gallery-item.component.css']
})
export class GalleryItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  image: Image;
  @Output() onDelete: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

 public deleteImage() {
  this.onDelete.emit();
 }
    }
```

in your parent component, add what should happen when onDeleteImage event triggers

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Image} from '../image';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery-container',
  template: '<app-gallery-item *ngFor="let image of images" [image]="image" (onDelete)="onDeleteImage(image)">\
    </app-gallery-item>',
  styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.css']
})
export class GalleryContainerComponent  {
  @Input()
  images: Image[];

  onDeleteImage(index: number) {
      this.images.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, there are no more errors, but the image is not deleted from the page. As if the page is not redrawn. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @senjust does the onDeleteImage function trigger?

Comment: I edited my answer, I changes the onDeleteImage function, check it out

Answer (score 1):

You need to emit event from GalleryItemComponent to GalleryContainerComponent so GalleryContainerComponent can delete image. You can have following code changes to accomplish this:

Inside GalleryItemComponent:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Image} from '../Image';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery-item',
  template: '<mat-card class="example-card">\
             <mat-card-header>\
               <mat-card-title>{{image.title}}</mat-card-title>\
            </mat-card-header>\
            <img mat-card-image [src]="image.url">\
            <button mat-button 
                 (click)="onDeleteImage(image.id)">DELETE</button>\
        </mat-card>',
  styleUrls: ['./gallery-item.component.css']
})
export class GalleryItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  image: Image;
  @Output() deleteImage: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  onDeleteImage(id){
     this.deleteImage.emit({imageId: id});
  }
```

}

Inside GalleryContainerComponent:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Image} from '../image';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-gallery-container',
    template: '<app-gallery-item (deleteImage)="onDeleteImage($event)" *ngFor="let image of images"\ 
               [image]="image">\
               </app-gallery-item>',
    styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.css']
})
export class GalleryContainerComponent  {
    @Input()
    images: Image[];

    onDeleteImage(event) {
        const index = event.imageId;
        console.log('Delete image');
        for (let i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
            if (this.images[i].id === index) {
                this.images.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In GalleryItemComponent, we are calling 'onDeleteImage()'. But the definition is inside the parent component GalleryContainerComponent.

You can fire an event using 'EventEmitter' from 'GalleryItemComponent' to 'GalleryContainerComponent'. Catch the event in GalleryContainerComponent template and call 'onDeleteImage()' method.

Comment: I would say this answer doesn't directly solves the problem. Adding the working code snippet will be really helpful to OP.